# Automapper executes without error, but no data being copied from source to destination

Tags: c#, deserialization, automapper

I have a class like this

```
public class ListOfBMTTeamMapping
{
    public class TeamMapping
    {
        public List<TeamMappings> results { get; set; }
    }
    public class TeamMappings
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string areaPath { get; set; }
        public string agileReleaseTrainName { get; set; }
        public string deliveryTeamName { get; set; }
        public string keyedInTeamCode { get; set; }
        public string deliveryTeamId { get; set; }
        public bool isDeleted { get; set; }
        public string modified { get; set; }
        public string modifiedBy { get; set; }


    }
}
```

And here is my model class to which I need the above API class to get copied

```
public class JsonBmtAdoMapping
{
    public int? Id { get; set; }
    public string AreaPath { get; set; }
    public string AgileReleaseTrainName { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryTeamName { get; set; }
    public string KeyedInTeamCode { get; set; }
    public string DeliveryTeamId { get; set; }
    public string IsDeleted { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Modified { get; set; }
    public string ModifiedBy { get; set; }
}
```

So here is my code I tried

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy"; 
var dateTimeConverter = new IsoDateTimeConverter { DateTimeFormat = format };
ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping Results = new ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping();
Results = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping>(responseBody);

List<JsonBmtAdoMapping> jM = new List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>();
jM = _mapper.Map<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping,List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>(Results);
int n = 10;
```

And here is my automapper profile

```
        CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping, List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>();
        
        CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMappings, JsonBmtAdoMapping>();
```

But when the code executes, Ofcourse I am getting the data in results variable without any trouble

But when the mapper code fires, it execute the line without any error, but no data being copied from source to my model class which is the destination

jM.count is always 0 when Results hold 124 rows of data

What I did wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your mapping from `TeamMapping` to `List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>` can't be done out of the box by AutoMapper, because your source is an object with a property that contains the list and the destination is a list on itself.

So you have to tell him, how this conversion from a single object to a list can be done. Due to the fact, that you already have a mapping for each individual item, we can use that recursively within our mapping method.

By using this mapping, it should work:

```
CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMappings, JsonBmtAdoMapping>();
CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping, List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, _, context) => src.results.Select(context.Mapper.Map<JsonBmtAdoMapping>).ToList());
```

#### Update

Cause a mapper is already defined for the individual items and lists are handled automatically by AutoMapper we can even make it shorter (thanks for Lucian for the hint in the comments):

```
CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMappings, JsonBmtAdoMapping>();
CreateMap<ListOfBMTTeamMapping.TeamMapping, List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>()
    .ConvertUsing((src, _, context) => context.Mapper.Map<List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>(src.results));
```

Comment: You don't need the `Select`, just map the collection.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Could you please share the code.

Comment: `ConvertUsing((src, _, context) => context.Mapper.Map<List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>(src.results))`

Comment: @Oliver Thanks a lot and Lucian.. But sorry to ask. I didnt understand this part
 (src, _, context) => context.Mapper.Map<List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>>(src.results)
What is that underscore there does

Comment: @SandeepThomas In a first place, the underscore in the above code is a variable name just like `src` or `context`. But due to the fact that this variable is not needed in our method call, I follow the convention to use an underscore as variable name to make clear, that this variable is not used by intention and not by fault. On the other side this variable can't be simply omitted from the call, cause it wouldn't match the signature, needed by the `ConvertUsing()` call.

Comment: @SandeepThomas This second parameter contains the value of the destination property. In our case it would be of type `List<JsonBmtAdoMapping>`. Cause we only use it to create new instances it will always be `null`. But if you would call `mapper.Map<TSource, TDestination>(TSource source, TDestination dest)` to map a source object on an existing destination instance, this can become handy to merge values (especially lists) within the destination object instead of replacing it.